# How can I convert an Nativescript App-application into a Web-application?

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am still a beginner in Nativescript/Angular and I want to know "How can I convert an app application into a web application or in a shared-application in nativescript?" to get it displayed on my Browser. Unfortunately there is no information on the internet. I have created a small app that shows listviews  and I would like to convert it. can someone help me ? I dont know how I can do that.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at Native Script Code Sharing

and

[NS Schematics](https://github.com/nativescript/nativescript-schematics)